# Azure Data Studio support for Catalina

Tags: azure, azure-data-studio

Is Catalina supported as part of Azure Data Studio?

The documentation here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-ver15) doesn't make mention of this specifically, and I got a following error, when going ahead with the install:

“Azure Data Studio” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This docs here for Azure Data Studio - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-ver15 now mentions Catalina support.